# Website not loading css, js, or images

Tags: javascript, css, http, https, web

I'm am working on a site for a client and am having trouble with the css, js, and images. The site is already live but I cannot findout why they wont load. The site loads in http and it seems like the css, js, and images are being called https so they are not being shown. Any advice on what to do would be wonderful! The website is shown below. Thanks!

[My Sky Realty](http://www.myskyrealty.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The website can't be accessed trough a HTTPS request... You must change the source to http:// instead of https:// (worked for me)

Comment: How do I go about doing that? Would it be a rewrite in the htaccess?

Comment: you have 2 options: 1. changing all the src="https://" to src="http://" (what I did) or you can make the entire website HTTPS. How do you do that? http://www.howto-expert.com/how-to-get-https-setting-up-ssl-on-your-website/ here is a good tutorial (the tutorial is free but making the website HTTPS will cost you some bucks) ...

Comment: Thank you I will try those options